Unity game crashes when opened through firebase notification
My game crashes whenever it's opened via the notification sent from firebase messaging. This happens when when you click on a button, for example: PLAY or Car Select etc.
Here is my firebase script:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Firebase.Messaging;
using Firebase.Extensions;
using Firebase;

public class FirebaseNotifications : MonoBehaviour
{
    // FirebaseApp instance
    Firebase.FirebaseApp app;

    void Start()
    {
        // Check Firebase dependencies
        Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
        {
            var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
            if (dependencyStatus == DependencyStatus.Available)
            {
                Debug.Log("Firebase dependencies are available.");

                // Subscribe to Firebase messaging events
                FirebaseMessaging.TokenReceived += TokenReceived;
                FirebaseMessaging.MessageReceived += MessageReceived;

                Debug.Log("Subscribed to Firebase events.");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
                  "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            }
        });
    }

    // Handle receiving a Firebase message
    private void MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the message and its notification payload are not null
        if (e.Message != null && e.Message.Notification != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("Notification received: " 
                      + e.Message.Notification.Title 
                      + "\n" 
                      + e.Message.Notification.Tag);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Received a message without a notification.");
        }
    }

    // Handle receiving a Firebase token
    private void TokenReceived(object sender, TokenReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Token Received: " + e.Token);
    }
}

here is the Logcat which mentions the crash error as:

2024/09/05 21:04:57.579 29243 29518 Error CRASH Forwarding signal 6
2024/09/05 21:04:58.034 29243 29518 Fatal libc Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 29518 (GC Finalizer), pid 29243 (ames.CarParking)
9:09
0001/01/01 00:00:00.000 -1 -1 Info  --------- beginning of crash

error screenshot:

Here is the video link of how it crashes on my phone:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ch9gsSksnzg

Do you have a stacktrace from Crashlytics or otherwise?

So what exactly happens when you click these buttons? I mean regarding your code .. you didn't share this and I'm not sure how exactly the code you provided relates to this crash .. and what is that package com.NSGames.CarParking ?
